# if range in rangelist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to find if a range is in a rangeList and I saw somewhere something like the statement:

```
if ( myrange in myrangelist ) ...
```

I have tried to get this to work but cannot.

Does someone know if possible and if yes then how?

Comment: I think that more information will help users think of the solution. Can you provide the sample values of a1Notation of `myrange` and `myrangelist`? And do you want to use all ranges of the range list as one range? Or for each range, do you want to check whether `myrange` is included in `myrangelist`? And also, when the part of `myrange` is included in `myrangelist`, what will you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
function isContainedInActiveRangeList(rgA1) {
  var rgA1=rgA1||'B2';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var list=sh.getActiveRangeList();
  var rgA=list.getRanges();
  var fulllist=[];
  for(var i=0;i<rgA.length;i++) {
    var rvA=rgA[i].getValues();
    var row=rgA[i].getRow();
    var col=rgA[i].getColumn();
    for(var j=0;j<rvA.length;j++) {
      for(var k=0;k<rvA[j].length;k++) {
        fulllist.push(sh.getRange(row+j,col+k).getA1Notation());
      }
    }
  }
  var trg=sh.getRange(rgA1);
  var tvA=trg.getValues();
  var trow=trg.getRow();
  var tcol=trg.getColumn();
  var cObj={ins:[],outs:[],fully:true,partially:false};
  for(var i=0;i<tvA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<tvA[i].length;j++) {
      var a1=sh.getRange(trow+i,tcol+j).getA1Notation();
      if(fulllist.indexOf(a1)>=0) {
        cObj.ins.push(a1);
      }else{
        cObj.outs.push(a1);
      }
    }
  }
  if(cObj.ins.length>0) {
    cObj.partially=true;
  }
  if(cObj.outs.length>0) {
    cObj.fully=false;
  }
  Logger.log(cObj);
  Logger.log(fulllist);
  return (cObj.fully)?true:false;
}
```

Comment: This would fail for a range of B2 and a RangeList of A2:C3. OP needs to provide more details to know what the type of `myrange` will be, and possible expected values.